# Add a new Excel Worksheet in C#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I was using NPOI plugin to export content as Excel file. The thing is that when the export file reaches the minimum export size (say like, 65535) then, it throws size limit exceeded exception. So I decided to go for creating another worksheet dynamically to amend the records after 65535. But I dont know how to write the logic for this. Please guide me how can i do the logic for this.

**Code**

```
                GridModel model = GetItems().AsQueryable().ToGridModel(page, int.MaxValue, orderBy, string.Empty, filter);
        var orders = model.Data.Cast<ViewModel>();

        //Create new Excel workbook
        var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        //Create new Excel sheet
        var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet();
        //int index = workbook.AddPicture(@"D:\Temp\2\autocomplete tables", HSS);
        //    HSSFPicture signaturePicture = patriarch.CreatePicture(anchor, index);
        ////(Optional) set the width of the columns
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(0, 10 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 20 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(2, 110 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(3, 30 * 256);

        //Create a header row
        var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);
        //Set the column names in the header row
        headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Itemid");
        headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("ItemNo");
        headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Title");
        headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Status");

        //(Optional) freeze the header row so it is not scrolled
        sheet.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);

        int rowNumber = 1;

        //Populate the sheet with values from the grid data
        foreach (ViewModel order in orders)
        {
            //Create a new row
            if (rowNumber < 65535)
            {
                var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber++);
                //Set values for the cells
                row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(order.Itemid);
                row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(order.INo);
                row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(order.BTags);
                row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(order.Sid);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        //Write the workbook to a memory stream
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        workbook.Write(output);

        //Return the result to the end user

        return File(output.ToArray(),   //The binary data of the XLS file
            "application/vnd.ms-excel", //MIME type of Excel files
            "Items.xls");     //Suggested file name in the "Save as" dialog which will be displayed to the end user
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
       object[,] objectrange;
        Excel.Range ExcelRangeNotFoundArticle;
        Excel.Application ActiveExelAplication = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application as Excel.Application;

        Excel.Worksheet ExNewWorksheet = ActiveExelAplication.Sheets.Add() as Excel.Worksheet;/*add new sheet here*/

        ExNewWorksheet.Name = ("sheetName");
        Excel.Worksheet ExWorksheet = ActiveExelAplication.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
        ExcelRangeNotFoundArticle = ExWorksheet.get_Range("a1", "am12") as Excel.Range;
        objectrange= (object[,])ExcelRangeNotFoundArticle.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below one will work for you:

```
    foreach (ViewModel order in orders)
    {

    if (rowNumber % 65535 == 0 )
        {   
    sheet = workbook.CreateSheet();
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(0, 10 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 20 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(2, 110 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(3, 30 * 256);

        headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Itemid");
        headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("ItemNo");
        headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Title");
        headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Status");

    sheet.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);
    //If you want row number should start from 1. Otherwise comment it
    rowNumber = 1;
    }   
        //Create a new row
        if (rowNumber < 65535)
        {
            var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber++);
            //Set values for the cells
            row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(order.Itemid);
            row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(order.INo);
            row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(order.BTags);
            row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(order.Sid);
        }
```